# Use of having cursor as output from oracle procedure

Tags: oracle

I am new to oracle .

I want to know what is cursor and is there any specefic reason for using them as output paramanter.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think rather than asking this question directly in the community you should have done some internet [search](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=what+is+a+cursor&oq=what+is+a+cursor&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.3826j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=what+is+a+cursor+oracle&spell=1) . The Reason I am telling you is that this is a standard forum and this is the reason why people come here and share question and experience(in form of answers)  and if you ask this type of non standard question the community will block you from asking question which would be huge loss from your side.

Comment: This is not an answer. I'm sure it is worthy for a comment though.